# Python списки, нужно из одного большого списка сделать большой с вложенными списками

Tags: python

```
Mas = ['Date,Visits,UniqueVisitors,Pageviews\n', '2018-01-01,10620,9575,45765\n', '2018-01-02,8912,8061,42513\n', '2018-01-03,9073,8074,42334\n', '2018-01-04,9225,8290,46141\n', '2018-01-05,14470,13253,74009\n', '2018-01-06,14082,12765,66577\n', '2018-01-07,9546,8724,43839\n', '2018-01-08,11048,9991,45218\n', '2018-01-09,8998,8043,42235\n', '2018-01-10,9574,8630,43817\n', '2018-01-11,8963,7858,43594\n', '2018-12-29,14926,13519,64790\n', '2018-12-30,13479,12252,57667\n', '2018-12-31,14162,12725,61492\n']
```

как из выше указанного сделать это

```
[ ['Date,Visits,UniqueVisitors,Pageviews'], ['2018-01-01,10620,9575,45765'], ['2018-01-02,8912,8061,42513'] , и так далее]
```

Answer (score 2):

А в чем проблема то?

```
res = [[obj[:-1]] for obj in Mas]
```

Comment: Спасибо ВАМ! если бы могли бы скинуть где почитать про эту технику или объяснить что конкретно делает эта часть [obj[:-1]

Comment: почитайте про списки и срезы (`[:]` - это срезы) - это база любого учебника по питону, срезы - так вообще база баз - ЛЮБОГО учебника